# Storing and Recalling Discord Colors

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I’m trying to make a bot where guilds can choose the color of their embeds. My only problem is storing those colors. This is some code as an example of what I’m trying to do.

```
color = None

@client.command()
async def setcolor(ctx):
    global color
    color = discord.Color.blue()
```

I want it so that I can call color in a separate command. The only problem is that I cannot call discord.Color.Blue. I have ways of storing it, but I am unable to call it. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: A database of sorts might work. What have you tried so far? Where in those attempts are you getting stuck? Show us these attempts, and see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Capitalization. All Discord colors are written in lowercase. Try `discord.Color.blue`

Comment: Thank you for that correction! Though my issue isn’t in calling the color, rather ways of storing it in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer! For anyone who is interested, I was able to store the color as a hex code instead. So instead of using `discord.Color.blue()`, I used its hex `0x3498db`

Answer (score 0):

You could make a dictionary and store the color names specific to the guild name
(EX:
{"guild name 1": discord.Color.Blue, "guild name 2": discord.Color.Red}

If you want to be less data intensive, or if this cant be run forever, I would use a SQL database.

In your code it would go like so:

```
colors = {}

@client.command()
async def setcolor(ctx):
    global color
    colors["guild name 1"] = discord.Color.Blue
```

Comment: Forgot to add this but, you would need a way to get the guild name

Comment: I’m sorry for my question being unclear. My problem is that I cannot call discord.Color.Blue for example. I have ways of storing it, but I am unable to call it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I am unaware with discord's API, but you would have to import discord from somewhere I presume